# Can't boot from my USB drive with Ubuntu on it?

Tags: thinkpad, mint

So my overall situation is I have an old IBM T42 thinkpad without a HDD. I'm trying to have it boot from a flash drive with linux mint on it. My main computer is an iMac with OSX.

I used Virtual box to run linux mint, and from there used Unebootin to put linux mint on to the flash drive (I used the cinnamon 17.2 64-bit install.)

Now when I try to boot on the IBM (I already changed the boot sequence in the BIOS) it will see the flash drive and I'm prompted to a Unebootin menu of sorts, but when I select "Start Linux Mint" I receive the following message:

"Invalid or corrupt kernel image.
boot:_"

Any thoughts as to what I'm doing wrong? Thanks!

Comment: Did you hashcheck the downloaded iso?

Comment: Hey thanks for commenting! No, I don't even know what that is...

Answer (score 0):

Some things to do after downloading the iso:

1. Did you md5sum check the downloaded iso?  See

   https://help.ubuntu.com/community/HowToMD5SUM
   Check the number
   against the listing in the link for your release listed at
   http://releases.ubuntu.com under the MD5SUMS link.
2. If using a     CD/DVD, did you burn the disc as slowly as possible?
   See
   https://help.ubuntu.com/community/BurningIsoHowto
3. Did you select the media check before trying to install?
   https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Installation/CDIntegrityCheck
4. Did you ever do a "memory check" (another live-media menu choice) on your PC?

Doing the above can save you a lot of time struggling with a bad install media.